# How to solve "ImportError: No module named networkx" in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-18.04

I want to use Ubuntu Terminal to execute .py file, but I have some problem.

```py
from ryu.base import app_manager
from ryu.controller import ofp_event
from ryu.controller.handler import MAIN_DISPATCHER, CONFIG_DISPATCHER
from ryu.controller.handler import set_ev_cls
from ryu.ofproto import ofproto_v1_3
from ryu.ofproto import ether

# packet

from ryu.lib.packet import packet, ethernet, arp

# topo
from ryu.topology import event, switches
from ryu.topology.api import get_switch, get_link

import networkx as nx

class shortest_path(app_manager.RyuApp):
    OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_3.OFP_VERSION]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(shortest_path, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.topology_api_app = self
        self.net = nx.DiGraph()
        self.switch_map = {}
        self.arp_table = {'10.0.0.1':'00:00:00:00:00:01',
                            '10.0.0.2':'00:00:00:00:00:02',
                            '10.0.0.3':'00:00:00:00:00:03'}

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures, CONFIG_DISPATCHER)
    def switch_features_handler(self, ev):
        dp = ev.msg.datapath
        ofp = dp.ofproto
        ofp_parser =dp.ofproto_parser

        self.switch_map.update({dp.id: dp}) 
        match = ofp_parser.OFPMatch(eth_dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
        action = ofp_parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofp.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS, [ofp_parser.OFPActionOutput(ofp.OFPP_CONTROLLER)])
        inst=[action]
        self.add_flow(dp=dp, match=match, inst=inst, table=0, priority=100)


    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPacketIn, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def packet_in_handler(self, ev):
        msg= ev.msg
        dp = msg.datapath
        ofp = dp.ofproto
        ofp_parser = dp.ofproto_parser

        port = msg.match['in_port']

        ## parses the packet
        pkt = packet.Packet(data=msg.data)
        # ethernet
        pkt_ethernet = pkt.get_protocol(ethernet.ethernet)

        if not pkt_ethernet:
            return

        # filters LLDP packet
        if pkt_ethernet.ethertype == 35020:
            return

        # arp
        pkt_arp = pkt.get_protocol(arp.arp)
        if pkt_ethernet.ethertype == 2054:
            print "arp"
            self.handle_arp(dp, port, pkt_ethernet, pkt_arp)
            return
        # forwarded by shortest path
        if not self.net.has_node(pkt_ethernet.src):
            print "add %s in self.net" % pkt_ethernet.src
            self.net.add_node(pkt_ethernet.src)
            self.net.add_edge(pkt_ethernet.src, dp.id)
            self.net.add_edge(dp.id, pkt_ethernet.src, {'port':port})
            print self.net.node

        if self.net.has_node(pkt_ethernet.dst):
            print "%s in self.net" % pkt_ethernet.dst
            path = nx.shortest_path(self.net, pkt_ethernet.src, pkt_ethernet.dst)
            next_match = ofp_parser.OFPMatch(eth_dst=pkt_ethernet.dst)
            back_match = ofp_parser.OFPMatch(eth_dst=pkt_ethernet.src)
            print path
            for on_path_switch in range(1, len(path)-1):
                now_switch = path[on_path_switch]
                next_switch = path[on_path_switch+1]
                back_switch = path[on_path_switch-1]
                next_port = self.net[now_switch][next_switch]['port']
                back_port = self.net[now_switch][back_switch]['port']
                action = ofp_parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofp.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS, [ofp_parser.OFPActionOutput(next_port)])
                inst = [action]
                self.add_flow(dp=self.switch_map[now_switch], match=next_match, inst=inst, table=0)

                action = ofp_parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofp.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS, [ofp_parser.OFPActionOutput(back_port)])
                inst = [action]
                self.add_flow(dp=self.switch_map[now_switch], match=back_match, inst=inst, table=0)
                print "now switch:%s" % now_switch
        else:
            return

    @set_ev_cls(event.EventSwitchEnter)
    def get_topology_data(self, ev):
        switch_list = get_switch(self.topology_api_app, None)
        switches =[switch.dp.id for switch in switch_list]
        links_list = get_link(self.topology_api_app, None)
        links=[(link.src.dpid,link.dst.dpid,{'port':link.src.port_no}) for link in links_list]
        print links     
        self.net.add_nodes_from(switches)
        self.net.add_edges_from(links)

    def add_flow(self, dp, cookie=0, match=None, inst=[], table=0, priority=10):
        ofp = dp.ofproto
        ofp_parser = dp.ofproto_parser

        buffer_id = ofp.OFP_NO_BUFFER

        mod = ofp_parser.OFPFlowMod(
                datapath=dp, cookie=cookie, table_id=table,
                command=ofp.OFPFC_ADD, priority=priority, buffer_id=buffer_id,
                out_port=ofp.OFPP_ANY, out_group=ofp.OFPG_ANY,
                match=match, instructions=inst
        )
        dp.send_msg(mod)

    def send_packet(self, dp, port, pkt):
        ofproto = dp.ofproto
        parser = dp.ofproto_parser
        pkt.serialize()
        data = pkt.data
        action = [parser.OFPActionOutput(port=port)]

        out = parser.OFPPacketOut(
                datapath=dp, buffer_id = ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER,
                in_port = ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,
                actions=action, data=data)

        dp.send_msg(out)

    def handle_arp(self, dp, port, pkt_ethernet, pkt_arp):
        if pkt_arp.opcode != arp.ARP_REQUEST:
            return

        if self.arp_table.get(pkt_arp.dst_ip) == None:
            return
        get_mac = self.arp_table[pkt_arp.dst_ip]


        pkt = packet.Packet()
        pkt.add_protocol(
            ethernet.ethernet(
                ethertype=ether.ETH_TYPE_ARP,
                dst = pkt_ethernet.src,
                src = get_mac
            )
        )

        pkt.add_protocol(
            arp.arp(
                opcode=arp.ARP_REPLY,
                src_mac= get_mac,
                src_ip = pkt_arp.dst_ip,
                dst_mac= pkt_arp.src_mac,
                dst_ip = pkt_arp.src_ip 
            )
        )

        self.send_packet(dp, port, pkt)
```

source code: https://github.com/YanHaoChen/Learning-SDN/blob/master/Controller/Ryu/ShortestPath/shortest_path_with_networkx.py

When I execute this python file, it gets this problem
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "shortest_path_with_networkx.py", line 16, in 
import networkx as nx
ImportError: No module named networkx

[image]
My pip version is 19.1.1 and Python version is 2.7
I must use Python 2.7~~~

Comment: did you install `pip install networkx`?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan When I installed networkx, I can solve this problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Please approve my answer due to it's your solution.tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install:

```
pip install networkx
```